# Intercept design-time dragging and resizing of custom WPF canvas child controls

Tags: wpf, canvas, design-time, adorner, arrangeoverride

I was able to add design-time adorner to a WPF control, but how do I take control over those built-into the designer? (in other words, I want my function to be called when anyone drags or resizes a control using standard designer's thumbs/rubber-bands/adorners/...)

.

**Below are details on what I am trying to accomplish**:

I'm writing a WPF Canvas-like control that has custom rules to place and size it's children. (it should also rotate, but that's another question)

```
<my:MyCustomCanvas> 
    <my:SomeControl my:Name="child control #1" Canvas.Left="20"  Canvas.Top="30"/> 
    <my:SomeOtherControl my:Name="child control #2" Canvas.Left="70"  Canvas.Top="80"/> 
</my:MyCustomCanvas>
```

One way to achieve this is overriding ArrangeOverride() like this:

```
public class CustomCanvas : Canvas
{
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            double left = child.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty) - this.GetValue(ActualWidthProperty) / 2;
            double top = child.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty) - this.GetValue(ActualHeightProperty) / 2;
            child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(left, top), child.DesiredSize));
        }
        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

It works, but if you try to drag or resize a child control in the designer, it jumps to where it would have been if it was on a normal WPF Canvas (i.e. X = Left , not X = Left - Width / 2  as ArrangeOverride dictates)

It looks like I need to take control of the designer. Microsoft even provided documentation how to do that: [Walkthrough: Creating a Design-time Adorner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907306%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It appears to work, however I failed to find a method to control how adorners *that are built into visual studio* work (those sizing thumbs that appear around a control when it is selected), only how to add *new ones*. Sure, I could just add few and instruct anyone not to touch standard ones, but it looks like an ugly kludge.

*For the purpose of* this *question it is safe to assume I have access to source code (i.e. can override methods) of both canvas, and its children, although methods that only need to alter parent canvas are preferred.*

[Official documentation on designer extensibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938.aspx) looks somewhat confusing to me. I had no luck searching the matter on the web either. So *any* useful clues will be greatly appreciated - like books, articles, examples, reference source links, etc.